# Installing MacOS via USB stick

Tags: macos, install, dual-boot

I have made a decision to install Mac OS from scratch so I have erased the disk part.(by cmd-r beginning of OS). Now, I'm using Windows(bootcamp). Is there any way to install Mac OS via USB stick and downloading, writing it into the USB on Windows?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can create a bootable USB that can automatically install OS X. It would mimic the functionality of the Recovery Disk option when booting. Here's a link from Macworld about how to do it with the latest version of OS X, Sierra. It's less complicated than it sounds. When you start your Mac, hold down the option key to choose the USB drive that you've created.

http://www.macworld.com/article/3092900/macs/how-to-create-a-bootable-macos-sierra-installer-drive.html

Comment: Your linked article assumes that you're using a Mac - unlike the questioner...

Comment: Marklark, he is using a Mac, running bootcamp to have a copy of Windows. I will say I don't understand the end of his sentence "writing it into the USB on Windows." If he's trying to have a virtual machine within bootcamp, he'd be better off just installing Windows on his Mac as the default OS.

Comment: @bocaboy, I suggest you reread the OP. It states "_I have made a decision to install Mac OS from scratch so I have erased the disk part.(by cmd-r beginning of OS)_" meaning he has erased the Macintosh HD from the Recovery HD. This means macOS is no longer available to work with other then the Recovery HD or his BOOTCAMP install of Windows. The latter per "_Now, I'm using Windows(bootcamp). Is there any way to install Mac OS via USB stick and downloading, writing it into the USB on Windows?_" So your answer does not address the situation and conditions under which itsnotmyrealname is operating!